# Best practices for designing an Angularjs Material mobile site - Viewport question

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material, material-design

I am starting to build my angularjs material mobile site. I am taking an existing desktop site already built and making it responsize for mobile.

I added the following tag in my header HTML code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Upon refreshing im noticing that everything now appears to be zoomed in and font size had increased. Ive been adding style tags to reduce the font size manually but its getting really teidous and this site needs to adjust to tablets as well.

Cant seem to find any documentation that shows best practices on how to handle this. Am I suppose to play with the `intial-scale` value in my `meta` tag and lower it until I find a sweet spot that would work ith all my devices? Or am I suppose to play with the CSS and lower the font size of all components manually?

I am a bit confused on what best practices are for this. The AngularJS Material website has no mention of viewport issues. Would anyone be able to assist or provide some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS Material works with breakpoints, as most style frameworks do.
You can find a reference for the breakpoints here: https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.5/layout/introduction

If you are new to responsive design, then you should start by some basics, as in what actually is a viewport, what does it mean?

> The browser's viewport is the area of the window in which web content
> can be seen. This is often not the same size as the rendered page, in
> which case the browser provides scrollbars for the user to scroll
> around and access all the content.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

In your meta tag, you define the viewport behavior, and what you defined is pretty much the standard to go by.

The reason why your font-sizes are changing is most likely because the app had initially styled them one way without a defined viewport, and now that your viewport has been defined, you're seeing a different scaling.

Now, another very important point I noted in the beginning is breakpoints, what are breakpoints and how do we use them? And to address a part of your own question, what's the best practice?

If you are familiar with classic CSS, then breakpoints can be referred to as media queries.

> Media queries are useful when you want to modify your site or app
> depending on a device's general type (such as print vs. screen) or
> specific characteristics and parameters (such as screen resolution or
> browser viewport width).

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Media queries are used to define style changes, based on a given device width (and/or height). In most cases, you go by the width definition alone (it's also what you'll see as referred units in various style library docs, such as AngularJS Material).

The exception to only defining media queries by width, is when you want to be very specific towards tablets. This is because bigger tablet sizes collide with desktop breakpoints, which is usually standardized to begin at 960px (sometimes you'll see 958px or 959.8px).

Now, what is considered best practice?

The best practice for responsive design is commonly referred to as the "mobile first" approach/design. You start by designing for the lowest screen resolution you want to support (280px for very outdated devices, 320px by today's standards) and work your way up.

> Mobile-first design is a key ingredient to successful product design.
> Designing for the smallest screens first, and then working your way up
> empowers designers to focus on the core functions of their product.
> When you focus on the core of your product and strip away the rest,
> you are able to pinpoint the most important UX components of the
> product.

Source: https://xd.adobe.com/ideas/process/ui-design/what-is-mobile-first-design/

Extra: https://anglestudios.co.uk/blog/why-mobile-first-web-design-is-becoming-more-important/

You can find various articles on the mobile approach very quickly by doing a very simple Google search query if you want more references etc.

My advice, would be to familiarize yourself by using the defined breakpoints in AngularJS Material, and use the same breakpoints in your own custom CSS if you want to apply more custom styling that's not easily achievable by native uses of AngularJS Material.

This way, you'll learn the basics, get familiar with the concept, and then, in the future, you can start thinking about incorporating things like NativeScript with Angular, which is what you'd ideally be using in a mobile app development environment.

> Today we’re happy to announce an exciting new way to build web and
> mobile apps with Angular and NativeScript.
>
> First, some background: since the beginning of Angular, you could use
> NativeScript with Angular to build mobile apps.
>
> NativeScript is an open source framework for building truly native
> mobile apps with JavaScript. It lets you use your existing Angular
> skills, and as a result you get a native UI & performance on iOS and
> Android.

Source: https://blog.angular.io/apps-that-work-natively-on-the-web-and-mobile-9b26852495e7

Link to NativeScript, [here](https://nativescript.org/).

Happy Learning & Coding!